# How to embed pdf in webpage with addon for adobe reader disabled in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to embed a pdf in my webpage. I used the `<embed>` tag for embedding it. But it is not working in Internet Explorer when addon for adobe reader is disabled. Can I have a solution which makes it work even addon for Adobe is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can use number of different plugins for embedding PDF on you website for:-

1. PDF Reader in JavaScript => [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)
2. PDF viewer:- [Viewer](http://viewerjs.org/)
3. Jquery :- http://www.bestjquery.com/2012/09/best-jquery-pdf-viewer-plugin-examples/
4. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-viewer
5. Angular :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer